# JavaScript: How to get two elements in a array to equal any given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

My question is:

If I have a array like this,
example:

`var myArray = [1,2,4,6,9]`

and I want to get the number 15 by getting (adding) the index of 6 and 9.

How do I do that?

I can't make it work and I have tried endlessly... please help.

My attempt:

```js
var list = [1,3,5,7,9]; 
function sumOfIndex(list , weight) { 
  weight = []; 
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
      list.push(weight); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show, what you tried?

Comment: var list = [1,3,5,7,9];


function sumOfIndex(list , weight) {
    weight = [];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
        list.push(weight);
            
        }
    }
}
This is what i tried, but i have not even been close to solve it.

Comment: there are some answers on this but your question is pretty unclear, are you trying to add up elements on given indices but do not know how? why is your example list different from code? is your expected output of your function simply 15?

Answer (score 0):

In the array from your example, the index of 6 is `[3]` and the index of 9 is `[4]`.

Simply add them together and you have 15.

Run the snippet below:

```js
var myArray = [1,2,4,6,9]

console.log(myArray[3] + myArray[4])
```

Comment: I think OP meant in a generic way, for a given array and sum to find

Answer (score 0):

I'd go over the array and create a map from the complement of each element to its index:

```js
function findSum (arr, sum) {
    const diffs = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (diffs.has(arr[i])) {
            return [diffs.get(arr[i]), i];
        }
        diffs.set(sum - arr[i], i);
    }
}
```